# Disabling nagios notification for a particular service

Tags: linux, notifications, nagios

I want to disable all nagios notifications for a particular service only. is it possible to do that with nagios? if yes how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In the service definition, set notifications_enabled to 0.  See [the doc](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#service).

Comment: What might come in handy is to define a base service type without notification (as suggested by this answer) and then derive the desired service from it.